# Can Pyarrow non-legacy parquet datasets read and write to Azure Blob? (legacy system and Dask are able to)

Tags: pyarrow

Is it possible to read a parquet dataset from Azure Blob using the new non-legacy?

I can read and write to blob storage with the old system where fs is fsspec:

```
pq.write_to_dataset(table=table.replace_schema_metadata(), 
                    root_path=path, 
                    partition_cols=[
                        'year',
                        'month',
                    ], 
                    filesystem=fs, 
                    version='2.0',
                    flavor='spark',
                   )
```

With Dask, I am able to read the data using storage options:

```
ddf = dd.read_parquet(path='abfs://analytics/iag-cargo/zendesk/ticket-metric-events', 
                     storage_options={
                          'account_name': base.login, 
                          'account_key': base.password,
                      })
```

But when I try using

```
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

dataset = ds.dataset()
```

Or

```
dataset = pq.ParquetDataset(path_or_paths=path,  filesystem=fs,  use_legacy_dataset=False)
```

I run into errors about invalid filesystem URIs. I tried every combination I could think of and tried to figure out how Dask and the legacy system can read and write files but the new one can't.

I'd like to test the row filtering and non-Hive partitioning.

Comment: you need a version of Spark with the hadoop-3.2 or later JARs; that's when abfs was added to hadoop-azure. And before you start thinking "what if I just drop in that later JAR alongside the usual hadoop-2.7 JARs?" -don't try. everything with hadoop- prefix needs to be in sync, just as the spark- JARs do

Comment: I have tested Spark (pyspark Jupyter Notebook image) and Apache Drill so I might have JARs somewhere that I am not aware of. But based on my current understanding, I am not using JARs for anything at this time - I am using just plain old Arrow or Dask/Pandas to read/write files to Azure Blob. I installed fsspec with pip and did not really configure anything.

Comment: .jar files are just binary files for the Java VM. Which spark runs on. You need the relevant files in your spark installation. How to do that is beyond my knowledge

Comment: Note this actually turned out to work with the latest versions of the libraries, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-9514

Comment: Nice - it does work. Are we able to write parquet datasets with the 'dataset' API? I would like to use the DirectoryPartitioning